# Showing and Hiding a container UIView with its subviews programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've got a label and a button side by side as shown as follows:

[image]

This is created by the following code:

```
private func addViewBack() {
    myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myLabel.text = "Show my label"

    myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myButton.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
    myButton.clipsToBounds = true

    containerView.backgroundColor = .red
    containerView.addSubview(myLabel)
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.addSubview(myButton)

    containerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myButton, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myLabel, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-8-[myLabel]-8-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["myLabel":myLabel]))
    containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[myLabel]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["myLabel":myLabel]))
    containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[myButton]-8-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["myButton":myButton]))
    containerView.layoutIfNeeded()

    self.view.addSubview(containerView)

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[topView]-100-[containerView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["containerView":containerView,"topView":viewTop]))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[containerView]-8-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["containerView":containerView]))
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I've got show and hide buttons that are supposed to show and hide the container view when pressing them as follows:

```
@IBAction func show(_ sender: Any) {

    if let constraint = (containerView.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .height}.first) {
        constraint.isActive = false
    }

    containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
}

@IBAction func hide(_ sender: Any) {
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
    containerView.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

When using the hide action, the button is never hidden and I end up with something like this:

[image]

When I add the following it works:

```
@IBAction func hide(_ sender: Any) {
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
    myButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
    containerView.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

When I press the show action, the button never reappears again like so:

[image]

How can I very simply show and hide elements in a container view using auto layout programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making the container view height constraint active/inactive, change its constant to zero to hide the container view. If its `clipsToBounds` is true, that will also hide the contents.